# Show only negative feedback of an Amazon seller

Tags: amazon

In the Amazon feedback page, there is shown all feedback of the last days/weeks/months, but there are only 5 records per page, and they are not sorted.

Is there a way to make Amazon visually show me all negative feedback of a seller?
Or sort by rating?

If it is not possible on the Amazon page itself, maybe there are external sites, that parse through all ratings? I could imagine a curl script, that scrapes all pages and extracts the negative feedback

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to see all of the individual feedback on the Seller. If you want to see individual reviews you will have to scroll or page through all of the reviews on the right hand side of their Seller page.

You can however see a summary of Seller feedback if you look at the Feedback History:
[image]

It sits just under the individual reviews